# Small area estimation - EBLUP

Tags: small-area-estimation

In small area estimation, the EBLUP (empirical best linear unbiased prediction) method is used for linear mixed models.

From this article on EBLUP: "A basic area-level model, called the Fay-Herriot (FH) model, is often used to obtain efficient estimators of area means when the sample sizes within areas are small. This model involves unobservable area random effects, and the empirical best linear unbiased predictor (EBLUP) of a small area mean is obtained by estimating the associated random effect. The EBLUP is a weighted combination of a direct area-specific estimator and a regression-synthetic estimator that uses all the data."
https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/12-001-x/2015001/article/14161/01-eng.htm

How does EBLUP improve upon estimators obtained by BLUP, and what considerations would affect the improvement in the fit of the model? Is the idea that by incorporating information on the variance estimator parameter (if known from say a prior experiment, or study) this is improving upon the direct sample variance?